# adding ChannelData in context while asking choices with PromptDialog.Choice bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have some custom data that I need to parse. I read for parsing custom data i.e. in HTML format we have something ChannelData in the IActivity.

PromptChoice.Choice(
                                            context,
                                            AfterOptionSelection,
                                             intentOptionModels,
                                             $"{returnMessage}"
                                            );

This is my code for asking some choices that I want to pass ChannelData in this context.

As I am not able to modify context here, is there any other way to parse ChannelData.

As I don't want to pass custom data through modifying options, I thought ChannelData is the best option for it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you explain the underlying problem, we can think of alternatives.

Comment: I am passing some sentiments based on my replies. These sentiments will be displayed as a bot icon in my webchat. I am using directline webchat for my bot

Comment: but why you need them in the context of a prompt choice?

Comment: I am passing my HTML from ChannelData. I want to set ChannelData in the context so that i can pass it in prompt choice, then i will get the activity at the web site and i am able to change the bot icon by using jquery.

Comment: I'm not fully following your scenario, sorry :(

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully follow either, but the bachchannel may be what you are looking for.  you can read about the backchannel towards the bottom of the [webchat readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and there are sample in the repo as well

Comment: just wanted to ask "can we modify the context and pass it while we are using PromptDialog.choice?"